# Cleaning Rmarkdown output

Tags: r, shiny, output, r-markdown, data-cleaning

The result of my rmarkdown document includes [n] and "", how can I remove them?

Eg. from [n] “Price:” “100” I want to get Price: 100.

where [n] is the number of the line

[IMAGE OF CURRENT OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vrg19.png)

R code

````
ui <- fluidPage( 
  sidebarLayout( 
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("price","Price:", value = "", placeholder = "00.0"),
    ), 
    mainPanel(
      h5(textOutput("price")),
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session){  
  
  output$price <- renderText({
    if(is.na(as.numeric(input$price))){
      stop(safeError("input correct price field"))
    }else{
      return(c("Price:",input$price))
    }
  })                          
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server) ```

Rmarkdown code

``` ---
title: ""
output: html_document
date: '2022-03-23'
---



```{r eruptions, echo=FALSE, results = 'asis', comment="", prompt=TRUE}

output_price <- reactive ({
  if (is.na(input$price)) {
    stop(safeError("input correct price field"))
  } else{
    return(c("Price:", input$price))
  }
})

return((output_price()))```
````

Comment: you are returning a vector `c("Price:",input$price)` I guess you want to return `paste0("Price: ", input$price)`

Comment: Well, I tried paste0 but the outcome rest the same, any other suggestions?

Comment: Just use `cat()` instead of `c()`.

Comment: Thank you solution found. I removed the "return" in the if cycle and substituted the return at the end with cat

Answer (score 0):

I could get price: 100 but had to move the `output_price<-...` in the server function() where a reactive is allowed.

see image with code in a single chunk in rmarkdown.

[image]

Comment: That's great, however, in my understanding, you are printing the output in the user interface whereas I would like to print it in rmarkdown. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: You mean when you run chunk ? The shiny environment in header will make sense to run it in shiny.  `---
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---
title: "some title"
output: html_document
date: '2022-03-23'
`    You can get the price: 100 in render if you put `cat("Price:", input$price)`  before return() in output_price() .  and isn't when you `run document` you get an rmarkdown output and there you are getting it. If you try to get inline `r cate("Price:",input$price) ` in rmarkdown, thats not working but you are getting it in ouput only.  Hoep someone gets your point and get back.